# Read file using in vue template

Tags: node.js, vue.js, fs

I need to read a file from the system in using `vue.js` 
Something like:

```
import fs from "fs"; 
var fs = require("fs"); 

fs.readFile("path");
```

I Have an error with importing `fs`. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please share the error you are getting so we can help you

Comment: It is not clear what are you trying to do. You want your Vue application to read a file that lives in the user computed? Or you want to read a file that lives in your server?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) for this purposes like this:

```
axios.get('/' + 'settings.json').then(response => {
     console.log(response.data);
     //do anything you want with response.data (content of the file)
})
```

Your file must be in a `public` folder